# TIFF image layer doesn't show on Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, geotiff-tiff, google-colab

Trying to display an image as layer on a Leaflet map but having some trouble. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
%pip install segment-geospatial groundingdino-py leafmap localtileserver

import leafmap
from samgeo import tms_to_geotiff, split_raster
from samgeo.text_sam import LangSAM

m = leafmap.Map(center=[24.8607, 67.0011], zoom=17, height="800px")
m.add_basemap("SATELLITE")
m

bbox = m.user_roi_bounds()

image = "Image.tif"
tms_to_geotiff(output=image, bbox=bbox, zoom=19, source="Satellite", overwrite=True)

m.layers[-1].visible = False
m.add_raster(image, layer_name="Image2")
m
```

Piece of code above results in output below, the image should be added as a layer to the map but doesn't show. I tried to convert it into .png and .jpg but this didn't do the trick.
[image: Output; blue square should be image]